# No such file or directory error in Jenkins shell script that works well in another jobs

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, scripting, sh

I have four different but very similar jobs in the same Jenkins instance and ran with the same user, that have the same shell step definition. The shell step definition is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
  echo $WORKSPACE
  cd $JENKINS_HOME/users/foo
  sh script.sh
```

When I execute the job, it throws the next error:

> cd: /var/lib/jenkins/users/foo: No such file or directory
>
> sh: script.sh: No such file or directory

In the other jobs that I have the same command sequence in the shell step, it works well and the *script.sh* is executed.

I have seen several posts and I have tried to change to `bin/bash`, execute the script directly with `source` or `./`, but none of the solutions worked.

Comment: No idea. Have you tried adding ls or find to your script so you can see what is in the folder?

Comment: Are you sure there is a directory at `/var/lib/jenkins/users/foo` wherever the job is ran?

Comment: The error says that the directory `/users/foo` doesn't exist. You should start there. You can add to your script commands like `ls $JENKINS_HOME/users` to see if the directory `foo` exists, looks like it will not be there. You can probably also connect to the Jenkins box and check the path. Not sure why 2 of your other jobs would work, perhaps they create the directory in some previous step and then remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already found the solution.
The problem was that the failed job was being executed in the slave node, and in the slave node, making a ls in the $JENKINS_HOME folder, there was no /users/foo folder at all.

So, I have marked that my failed job ran in the principal node instead of the slave node. I have executed the job again and now it works well.

The problem, in fact, was that the principal and slave nodes in Jenkins server weren't synchronized correctly.